# In MySQL, how to copy records between tables, and add my own value at the same time?

Tags: mysql, insert, copy

I'm copying data from PharmacyData to fl_admin via like this:

```
INSERT INTO fl_admin (first_name, last_name, email)
    SELECT ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, ContactEmail FROM PharmacyData
```

At the same time, I'd like to populate another column in fl_admin called "type" with the value "pharmacy".  How can I do this in the same SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO fl_admin (type, first_name, last_name, email)
    SELECT 'pharmacy', ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, ContactEmail FROM PharmacyData
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO fl_admin (type, first_name, last_name, email) SELECT 'pharmacy', ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, ContactEmail FROM PharmacyData
```

Answer (score 0):

I just do it this way

```
INSERT INTO fl_admin (first_name, last_name, email, type)
    SELECT ContactFirstName, ContactLastName, ContactEmail, 'pharmacy' FROM PharmacyData
```